# Update OPTIONS in SELECT B from MYSQL when SELECT A is changed in form

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, forms

**How do I populate a select box in my form with only products that match group selected in another select box?**

I am using two tables in the mySQL database:

```
GROUP "node"
nid | title
g1   | Group 1
g2   | Group 2

GROUP "products"
id  | name        | parent_id | group_id
p1  | Product 1   | p1        | g1
p2  | Product 2   | p1        | g1
p3  | Product 3   | p3        | g1
p4  | Product 4   | p4        | g2
p5  | Product 5   | p5        | g2
p6  | Product 6   | p5        | g2
```

When adding a product using the form, the administrator should be able to select the GROUP and PARENT PRODUCT. This is functioning with my code:

```
<li>
                <label for="group">Group</label>
                <select name="group">
                    <?php
                    //get group names
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT nid, title FROM node WHERE type = 'group';");
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

                            <option value="<?php echo $row['nid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></option>


                        <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </li>


            <li>
                <label for="parent">Parent</label>
                <select name="parent">
                <?php
                //get parent names
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, group_id FROM products");
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>

                        <option value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>

                    <?php }?>
                </select>
            </li>
```

However, I would like to have the PARENT (parent product) select box populate only with the products that are a part of the group that was selected.

In the example database, "Group 1" selected would populate products p1, p2 and p3. "Group 2" selected would populate products p4, p5 and p6.

I know that this can't be done with straight PHP, but will require some kind of javascript to detect the group_id / nid in both tables and display only products with that group_id.

What is the best way to do this? How would I accomplish this easily?

Answer (score 0):

Depends.  If you want to use Javascript, you can use AJAX.

To do this, you first bind a function to the event "change" of your first select.

With jQuery you can create a function and bind it:

```
pull_products_by_group = function(this) {
  // Use AJAX here
}

$('select[name="group"]').change(pull_products_by_group);
```

Then you use AJAX in this function to call some new script that will select from the products table.  You can have this function returns JSON (normally recommended) or straight HTML (if you insist).

If you do not want to use javascript, then you must add a button that the user will click after choosing the group, which will reload itself (the php script) which will receive the selected group and you can redisplay the same page but this time with the list of products.

Comment: Sounds great, but I'm unfamiliar with AJAX and what code to use in order to get the info from the database and match it to what was selected.

Comment: I recommend you get familiar with AJAX because copying/pasting code that you do not understand will not help you.  It will not work and you will not know why.  I recommend starting here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31155/Ajax-Tutorial-for-Beginners-Part-1